# Median-Filter vs. morphological operators on binary images to reduce noise

Tags: image-processing

Typically I use a Median-Filter on grayscale images to reduce Salt- and Peppernoise and morphologicial operators to do the same in binary pictures. Now a colleague asked me why I don't use the Median on binary images too instead of erosion and dilation.
I wasn't able to answer it and I'm a little bit puzzled about this. Could you help me and tell me if it is a bad or a good idea to use a Median-Filter to reduce noise in binary images?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean opening and closing, because just erosion/dilation produce a bigger deformation of your original signal.

Use a "small" median filter instead of a "small" opening/closing should be relatively comparable on binary images.

On gray level image, a median filter should be less "aggressive", because is uses the median value (instead of the minimum/maximum), and thus it should be provide a better preservation of the original signal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is a matter of control and strength.

The binary images are often segmented labels. This segmentation is always imperfect, with peaks, capes, small holes and small islands often appearing. Morphological opening removes completely any regions of an object which can not contain the structuring element. Morphological closing removes completely any regions of an object which can be completely contained inside the structuring element. Median filtering might leave parts of an hole untouched if it is near enough a border or set inside a cape. It also might leave areas of salt and pepper noise intact if the local density is high enough, which morphological opening will never do.

If your binary images do not have any local unwanted clusters then the behaviour is pretty much similiar. If they do, morphological operators are more likely to scrub them off. The shape of the structuring element also lets you choose what kind of artifacts you wish to remove.